# change cursor focus after filling input field to next input

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm working on a project where I use javascript to create a random number of input fields with `maxlength = "1"` and when the user fills all of them with one letter each a submit button appears .
The problem is that when a field is filled I want the cursor to move to the next input field . I am trying to add this functionality to my input elements using an `eventlistener` with the `onkeyup` event . However when I implement this in code the cursor movement functionality is not working and when I inspect my page I see no errors .

My code :
https://jsfiddle.net/bill_sk/2t7vLc5y/2/

I would appreciate your help with this . Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputLists.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
        if(input.value.length === input.maxLength && parseInt(input.id) < inputLists.length) {
                  document.getElementById(parseInt(input.id)+1).focus();
        }
      })
```

- input.id will give you a string, so you have to parse it to int.
- event should be "keyup", and not "onkeyup"
- always look out for the last element in an array when you want add something to the next element in a for cycle
- use the inputList variable that you initialize at the top of the function, the code    will be more readable

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try `"keyup"` instead of `"onkeyup"`.
If you are working on something like this, always try to find out, which part of the code is not working with `console.log()`
There were some other mistakes, but this works

```
elem.addEventListener("keyup" , evt => {
                
          elem = evt.target
          if(elem.value.length >= elem.maxLength){
              let el = document.getElementById(parseInt(elem.id) +1)
              el.focus();

          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to listen to the `keyup` event not the `onkeyup` event

```
elem.addEventListener("keyup" , evt => {
```

and then get the next input element like this

```
let el = document.getElementById(parseInt(elem.id) +1).focus();
```